# mouseEvent в QPushButton

Tags: c++, qt5

Возникла такая проблема: создал класс, унаследовавшись от `QPushButton` и обнаружил, что не могу переопределить `mouseReleaseEvent` так как он не является виртуальным. Мне нужно, чтобы кнопка при нажатии на нее правой кнопкой реагировала по-другому, но, так как этот метод я не могу переопределить, то не знаю как это сделать. Вариант с наследованием от `QAbstractButton` рассматривать не хочется, так как `QPushButton` и так соответствует всем моим требованием (за исключением этого-вот момента).

Как заставить кнопку реагировать на правую кнопку мыши (выполнять действия отличные от тех, что выполняются при нажатии левой кнопки)?

UPD Данная проблема связана с опечаткой, вопрос, по-сути, не имеет смысла.

Comment: А в чем проблема? Переопределяете метод mouseReleaseEvent, вызываете родительский метод mouseReleaseEvent: `QPushButton::mouseReleaseEvent(event);`

Comment: @gil9red так он не виртуальный - как его переопределить?

Comment: Сейчас я возможно затупил, но любой метод ведь можно переопределить, разве нет? Он ведь не приватный. Кст, по нашей теме код: https://github.com/search?q=QPushButton+mouseReleaseEvent&type=Code

Comment: @gil9red переопределить можно только виртуальный метод - вы путаете с перегрузкой.

Comment: Перегрузка и переопределение разные вещи, вы ведь не меняете семантику метода mouseReleaseEvent

Comment: Переопределить можно любой метод, виртуальные методы нужны не для переопределения. Покажите, как вы переопределяете и что именно подразумевается под "не могу переопределить"

Comment: Ошибка оказалась в моей невинмательности - допустил опечатку при переопределении метода и он, конечно же, не помечался как `override`. Вопрос закрою, так как проблема, понятное дело, не воспроизводится

Comment: ан, нет, удалить уже не получится

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Согласно документации Qt http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#mouseReleaseEvent

Метод `QWidget::mouseReleaseEvent` является виртуальным. Можете поподробней описать, как Вы пытались переопределить метод?

```
#include <QApplication>

#include <QPushButton>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QMessageBox>

class MyButton : public QPushButton
{
public:
    MyButton(QWidget *parent = nullptr):
        QPushButton(parent)
    {


    }


protected:
    virtual void mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent *event) override
    {
        QMessageBox::information(this, "", "WOW It's mouseReleaseEvent");
        QPushButton::mouseReleaseEvent(event);
    }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MyButton w;
    w.setText("MY BUTTON");
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: подробнее посмотрите в вопросе - я четко указал, что наследуюсь от `QPushButton` а не от `QWidget`. Удалите ответ - ответы не место для комментариев, я думаю вы это и так должны знать

Comment: QPushButtion унаследован от QWidget и метод mouseReleaseEvent объявлен именно в QWidget

Comment: во-первых, не от `QWidget`, а от `QAbstractButton`. Во-вторых, для перегрузки он должен быть указан как виртуальный для класса, от которого наследуемся. В-третьих, удалите все-таки ответ, как не соответсвующий требованиям форума

Comment: @Andrej Levkovitch а ``QAbstractButton`` от кого наследован? Если Вас смущает, что в заголовочном файле ``QAbstractButton`` метод ``void mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent *e)`` не имеет ключевого слова ``virtual``, так ознакомьтесь с основами c++ - это вовсе не обязательно.

Comment: а вы уверены в том, что в `QAbstractButton` этот метод не объявлен как `virtual`? В любом случае спасибо - нашел ошибку, оказалось что при определении этого метода допустил опечатку, которую не заметил и из-за которой, конечно-же, не переопределялся этот метод. Вопрос будет закрыт

Comment: @Andrej Levkovitch используйте ключевое слово ``override`` при переопределение методов, тогда в случае "случайных ошибок" Вы получите ошибку компиляции.

Comment: я и так использую override - поэтому и решил, что метод нельзя переопределить, так как у меня выбивалось что, это не виртуальный метод. В любом случае, вопрос был задан зря

Answer (score 2):

Установите фильтр событий (`installEventFilter`) и добавляйте туда необходимую логику.